# stop duplicate entry after reload browser

Tags: php

I have a form and trying to insert data in table with class. Data is inserting in proper way.
But when click on browser reload after insert query, then it inserts duplicate entry in table.
I tried it with redirect function. But not working.

**My form is:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['insertcourse']))
    { 
 $userprofileobj->insert_course($_POST['c_name'],$_POST['c_description']);
    }
?>
 <form action="" method="POST">
 <div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Course Name :</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" class="span11" placeholder="First name" name="c_name" />
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="control-label">Course Description :</label>
     <textarea class="textarea_editor span12" rows="6" placeholder="Enter text ..." name="c_description"></textarea>
     </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
     <input type="submit" value="SAVE" name="insertcourse" class="btn btn-success">
      </div>
      </form>
```

**My classes.php is:**

```
<?php
class operations{

public $user_name;
public $error;
public $con;


public function __construct()
{       
    $this->con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","admin_with_oops");
}
public function insert_course($c_name,$c_description)
{
    $date1 = date("Y-m-d");
    $result = $this->con->query("insert into courses (c_name,c_description,date1,status1) VALUES ('$c_name', '$c_description', '$date1','1')");
    if($result)
    {
        $alertmsgs = "Inserted Successfully";
        $this->alertmsg($alertmsgs);

    }
}
public function alertmsg($alertmsgs)
{
    echo"<div class='alert alert-error'>
          <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button>
          <strong></strong> $alertmsgs </div>
      </div>";
}
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get ... also your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY)

Comment: Check if that course already exists beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [generate a guid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php) and put it in a hidden input in your form. Database that ID on the initial submit and don't allow it to be inserted a second time.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php com_create_guid() ?>">
```

It's a little more foolproof than post-redirect-get and will be a less jarring user experience, especially over high latency networks.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But can I directly call redirect function in class?

Comment: Any other way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by calling the function in the class. The purpose of the hidden guid input is to place something unique in the browser that will identify the form when it is posted. If you calculated the guid in the class during the POST operation, it would be re-generated for each POST, defeating the purpose of the guid. If you're just asking whether you can place the guid creation method in your class for organizational purposes, sure I guess so. Just make sure you call it on the GET request to set the value of the hidden input.